# Error while trying to access public stories from Medium API on client side

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-browser, axios, medium.com-publishing-api

I'm trying to access Medium's API to get a list of public stories from a user. However, I'm getting a CORS error when I try to access it on the client side. Here's the code

```
axios.get(`http://medium.com/@ev/latest`).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error)
})
```

I did some research and found this [github issue](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/issues/51), but couldn't find any workaround. Is there any way to make this request work on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the HTML from https://medium.com/@ev/latest by making your request through a CORS proxy — either a proxy you set up yourself or else just by using a public open CORS proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. Here’s how to do it using the standard Fetch API:

```js
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://medium.com/@ev/latest")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = text)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

For more details — including how to set up your own CORS proxy on Heroku in just a few minutes, see *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* in the answer at *[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141)*.

---

Incidentally, if instead you want JSON, you can try https://medium.com/@ev/latest?format=json but you’ll find that what you get back isn’t actually valid JSON; instead it starts out like this:

```
])}while(1);</x>{"success":true,"payload":{"user":{"userId":"268314bb7e7e","name"…
```

Apparently that’s intentional, [per a comment from a Medium developer in their issue tracker](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/issues/51#issuecomment-267711057):

> The JSON page is not intended to be used as a read API. The extra code is there to support our own use and is a standard technique to avoid JSON hijacking.

That’s trivial to work around, though: Just first handle the response as text in your client code, and strip out the `])}while(1);</x>` from the start of it, and then run `JSON.parse` on what remains.

But as far as using Axios to get the response as text, I think you’ll find it’s not going to work as expected even if you make the request through a CORS proxy; try this:

```js
axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://medium.com/@ev/latest', {
    responseType: 'text'
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(error => console.log("ERROR"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

The code hits the `catch` because apparently even when you specify `responseType: 'text'`, [Axios apparently still tries the parse the response as JSON](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/907#issuecomment-322054564):

> This is because `JSON.parse` is always tried in the response, even if `responseType` is text. We should fix that indeed.

And https://medium.com/@ev/latest is HTML, not JSON, so running `JSON.parse` on it will fail.

That’s why the first snippet in this answer uses the Fetch API instead (you can get text back with it).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not allowed by Medium (There server doesn't respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header). Probably because of security concerns.

As suggested in the GitHub issue you linked to, a possible solution will be to tunnel the request to Medium through your server (as proxy). You can create an endpoint on your server (i.e. `http://my-server.com/get-medium/@ev/latest`) that will retrieve the requested Medium page (on the server side) and will return it to the client side.

This comment to the issue describes a way to do that using AWS Lambda as the proxy server - [link](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/issues/51#issuecomment-278467906)